# Which component controls the "universal" app background

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

On Gingerbread, which component(like SystemUI.apk) controls the universal background?

To better explain myself, here is a screenshot

[image]

I'm referring to the blue background with the gradients

Comment: Which device are you using? It looks like that is not a universal background, but rather simply the background for the Settings app. Does the background show up anywhere else besides when you go to Settings?

Comment: Yeah it does. Some examples include Root Explorer, the blank area of the dialer e.t.c . I no longer use this rom (If your wondering, its Technoduos 1.5 on Samsung Galaxy Y)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a system theme. Any app that is written to run under the theme of the device (unless you're root your devices theme is not changeable) will grab backgrounds, etc from that theme. It is like how most apps on the Nexus devices run with the Holo theme.

Edit: Just to clarify I am saying this is not an app, it is just a theme.